# Azure DevOps: approve Pull Request programatically

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using `$Project Build Service ($org)` account to create and merge PR (`release/*` into `master` after successful release)

..but it requires `Bypass policies when completing pull requests` option to be enabled for `$Project Build Service ($org)` account in scope of target branch

I can add `$Project Build Service ($org)` account as a reviewer for PRs to `master` but is there a way to approve PR in Azure DevOps programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to approve PR in Azure DevOps programatically?

You can use the REST API [Pull Request Reviewers - Create Pull Request Reviewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull-request-reviewers/create-pull-request-reviewer?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) to approve pull request.

```
PUT https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/pullRequests/{pullRequestId}/reviewers/{reviewerId}?api-version=6.0
```

Here is an example of request body:

```
{
    "vote": 10
}
```

The value of vote sets the state of the review:

10 - approved

5 - approved with suggestions

0 - no vote

-5 - waiting for author

-10 - rejected

Comment: Does not work anymore?

Comment: @YogeeshSeralathan Thank you for your feedback! The link was invalid. I changed it to the new one.